# Jackson - suppressing serialization(write) of properties dynamically

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to convert java object to JSON object in Tomcat/jersey using Jackson. And want to suppress serialization(write) of certain properties dynamically.

I can use JsonIgnore, but I want to make the ignore decision at runtime. Any ideas??

So as an example below, I want to suppress "id" field when i serialize the User object to JSON..

```
new ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);


class User {

private String id = null;
private String firstName = null;
private String lastName = null;

//getters
//setters

}//end class
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, JSON View is the way to go.

If you e.g. need to let the client to decide which fields to marshal, this example might help: http://svn.codehaus.org/jackson/tags/1.6/1.6.3/src/sample/CustomSerializationView.java

Comment: That link requires authentication

Comment: That link doesn't work anymore, but I'm assuming the following link will be an equivalent..
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-1/blob/master/src/sample/sample/CustomSerializationView.java

Answer (score 2):

Check

```
ObjectMapper.configure(SerialiationJson.Feature f, boolean value)
```

and

```
org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore
```

annotation

This will work only when you want all instances of a certain type to ignore id on serialization. If you truly want dynamic (aka per instance customization) you will probabily have to hack the jackson library yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way of doing that. If you need to dynamically decide which properties are marshalled, then I suggest you manually construct a `Map` of keys to values for your objects, and then pass that `Map` to Jackson, rather than passing the `User` object directly.

Comment: thanks. I think the Map pattern is a little weak too, when it comes to creating JSON arrays.

Map<String,Object> map1 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map1.put("fname", "Steve");
map1.put("lname", "Colly");
  
Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map2.put("fname", "Josh");
map2.put("lname", "Roff");

List jsonArray = new ArrayList();
jsonArray.add(map1);
jsonArray.add(map2);

new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(jsonArray) 

...does not produce???

[{'fname':'Steve','lname':'Colly'},{'fname':'Josh','lname':'Roff'}]

Comment: @kapil.isr: Yes it does, I just tried it, it works fine. The order of the keys is different, but that's because you used a `HashMap` rather than a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Also do you know if ObjectMapper can be shared among threads, i know doc says it can. But I just wanted to make sure, if thats the case. There doesn't seem to be whole lot of information on jackson out there, their own doc seems limited.

Comment: `ObjectMapper` can be shared, yes.

Comment: I am not quite sure why you would doubt explicit guarantee by author(s) of the library (I assume you refer to http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ, "Is ObjectMapper thread-safe? "), but yes, it is fully shareable as long as you do not try changing configuration settings when sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [JSON Views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews)?
Views allow annotation-based mechanism for defining different profiles, so if you just need slightly differing views for different users, this could work for you.