# Don't return property when it's an empty list with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class need to be dessrialized using jackson and the class has an collection property. The collection is empty, but not null. 
Question: How to desersialise the class **without** empty collection. Sample code below:

```
class Person
{
    String name;
    List<Event> events;
    //....getter, setter
}
```

if

```
person.list = new List<Event>(); 
persion.name = "hello";
```

then excepted the json would be:

```
{name: "hello"}
```

not

```
{name: "hello", events:[]}
```

How to make it? Thank you~~

================================================

I have solved this by n1ckolas's advice. Thank you first.
My jackson version is 2.1.1, and Spring-3.2.2 import better support for this verson of jackson. Also, this works for both  **arrays and collection.**
Below is my configuraion:

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>        
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<!--Json Mapper-->
<bean name="objectMapper" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean" autowire="no">
    <property name="featuresToDisable">
        <list>
            <!--not to return empty colletion-->
            <value type="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature">WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you can change your original model with Jackson annotations, here is the way how to achieve this.

Jackson has [WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-Features). And you may turn off it with:

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, false);
```

But it works only for `Arrays`, but not for `Collections`. But you may combine `@JsonProperty` with `@JsonIgnore`, something like the following:

```
//....getter, setter of Person class
@JsonIgnore
public List<Event> getEvents() {
    return events;
}

@JsonProperty("events")
public Event[] getEventsArr() {
    return events.toArray(new Event[0]);
}
```

And afterwards you'll have output, as you expected.

**EDIT**: If you are using SpringMVC, then you can configure your actual `ObjectMapper` with explicit reference in `mvc:annotation-driven`:

```
<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<!--custom Json Mapper configuration-->
<bean name="objectMapper" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.JacksonObjectMapperFactoryBean" autowire="no">
    <property name="featuresToDisable">
        <list>
            <!--Ignore unknown properties-->
            <value type="org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature">WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

*Offtop:* usually it's quite useful to specify explicit instance of `ObjectMapper`, because:

- you can configure it in the way you want
- you can use its reference through `@Autowired`

Comment: Can I use this in annotation? I use springmvc @ResponseBody for auto deserialization:
  
     objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, false)

Comment: I use Jackson version 2.x. Do you know how to configure?

Comment: I have solved it! Thank you! For jackson2, please find more answer updated in my questoin.

Comment: Jackson 2.x is:
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, false);

Answer (score 71):

You can use @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) annotation on your class or filed.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
class Person
{
    String name;
    List<Event> events;
    //....getter, setter
}
```

Comment: Worked for my case of ArrayList<Object>

Comment: This is the best answer in contrast to the currently selected answer, which is Deprecated!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Spring Boot, just add in your `application.properties` the following :

```
spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=NON_EMPTY
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. However, this did: `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_EMPTY`

Answer (score 5):

Use this annotation  `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)`

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
person.list = new List<Event>();
```

from documentation

> Value that indicates that only properties with null value, or what is
>   considered empty, are not to be included.

Answer (score 3):

Spring boot automatically picks the property from the application.properties
you can add below property:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-empty-json-arrays=false
```

Comment: @deprecated Since 2.8 there are better mechanism for specifying filtering; specifically
  using {@link com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude} or configuration overrides.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use JSON View, like in here : [Jackson - suppressing serialization(write) of properties dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981359/jackson-suppressing-serializationwrite-of-properties-dynamically/4422029#4422029)
2. Another way to do it is to define another class, almost similar with `Person`, but without the `events` property. Then based on the value of the collections, you can decide to serialize the original `Person` object, or the alternative, `events`-less object. This is IMHO simpler, and should works for your case above, but not as flexible as the first alternative.

Answer (score 0):

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) Include this, at class level, will do following things.

1. Include only not null values
2. Include only non empty list