# Remove empty JSON objects from an array in Jackson serialization

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson2

I have a List in a Java Pojo class. That list contains some MyChildPojo objects which are not null but can have properties with null values. Example:

```
MyChildPojo obj1 = new MyChildPojo();
MyChildPojo obj2 = new MyChildPojo();
```

I have added `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` on my MyChildPojo class so null properties will not be added while serializing the object.
Now my final serialized output for the List object is:

```
[
  {}, {}
]
```

I want to remove the complete List object in this case. I have tried by adding `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` and `@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_EMPTY, content = Include.NON_EMPTY)` on the List object but still getting the same output.

I can only use annotation in my case. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't return property when it's an empty list with jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426232/dont-return-property-when-its-an-empty-list-with-jackson). You said "only annotations", but if you can add an annotation, I think you should also be able to set the `WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS` property.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. It is very similar to my use case. But in my case it is [{}, {}] and not []. So it will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use annotations with custom filter to do this. In the custom filter you can omit the list property altogether when the whole set of `MyChildPojo` objects are just shell.

Annotate `MyChildPojo` class with

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY, valueFilter = EmptyListFilter.class)
public class MyChildPojo {
...
}
```

And define `EmptyListFilter` something like the following

```
public class EmptyListFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof List)) {return false;}
        Optional<Object> result = ((List)obj).stream().filter(
                eachObj -> Arrays.asList(eachObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()).stream().filter(eachField -> {
                    try {
                        eachField.setAccessible(true);
                        if ( eachField.get(eachObj)  != null && !eachField.get(eachObj).toString().isEmpty()) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return false;
                }).count() > 0).findAny();
       return  !result.isPresent();
    }
}
```

Example uses the following dependencies on `Java:8`

```
   compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.11.0'
   compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.4'
```